# Omitted current job as forgot to send updated CV and got job offer

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, work-experience, background-check, onboarding

I have a strange situation where I was interning with a company for 6 months and they offered me a full time position in . I had applied to another job in July with my CV as an intern showing as my current job.

Their process took a while and I got my final offer from them a few months later . I interviewed with them in August and September but I forgot to send them my new CV with my full time position. I talked about my new role during the interview vaguely.

I finally got a job offer end of the year and I sent an updated version of my CV to the background screening company. Now I realize that the recruiter and HR might not be aware of my change in position. I am afraid it is too late and I will lose the job if I mention it. What do I do?

Comment: The only reason this might actually affect your new company is if you have to give a different notice period to your current company. That would affect your proposed start date (but probably nothing else). Do you have a change in notice period?

Comment: You didn't omit anything, at the time you gave them the CV, you didn't have that job.

Comment: Sounds like you did everything right - you submitted a CV and then, months later, you submitted an updated one when requested.  I'm struggling to see an issue here!

Answer (score 81):

This is a non-issue. Your current company hasn’t changed, only your position/role/title.

Answer (score 21):

This seems like an honest mistake - an omission on your part. Since you haven't lied about your position, but simply forgotten to update your CV, I would expect the worst outcome to be a question with regards to this.

I can hardly imagine them retracting the job offer over this. If they do, you may want to approach them, but this may also be considered unreasonable, and thus a sign you may not want to work there after all.

I wouldn't sweat it - if they do get back to you, explain the situation.
Otherwise, accept the job offer and start the new job.

Comment: I'm not even sure I'd call it a mistake, and you did nothing wrong : at the time you sent your CV it was up to date, and the "missing information" has no reason to be a game changer. They have asked you a CV at a certain date (July), if they want an update every time something changes they should state it (or process candidates faster). If they really care about the few missing months between the end of your internship on the CV and October, they can ask you an updated CV. If they don't, they probably don't care.

Comment: @SOSpleasehelp I'd do nothing about this, and assume nothing will come out of it.

Answer (score 7):

Your location might matter, but in the US your resume is marketing material, not some legal document--there's just no requirement to list everything on your resume. So you would be perfectly fine to leave it off deliberately or accidentally. (It's actually really common to leave things off. When you're young you're usually including everything just to pad out your resume, but at some point you have so much stuff that you leave off anything that doesn't actually enhance your resume for the specific job that you're applying to.)

There are actual legal documents where you do have to list everything...for example, when you pay your taxes, or if you get some job requiring a security clearance, but they should give you a clearly marked form for that.

Comment: I mean, it would be fraud if you lied on your resume and were hired as a result of those lies. And conceivably, you could be sued for damages, namely the money they spent hiring you. It's unlikely anyone would pursue such a legal battle though.

Comment: @corsiKa There's a difference between a direct lie and an omission here. If you said "this is every job I've ever had" and then left something off, sure, that's a problem, but if you don't specifically go out of your way to say that then there's just no implication that your resume is every job ever. Like the job advert probably lists some technologies that they want you to know, and then you show up and day 1 you are working on much less exciting stuff...no implication that the job advert listed _everything_ you would do.

Comment: perhaps, but your opening statement "not some legal document" is simply false.

Comment: @corsiKa https://www.google.com/search?q=is+a+resume+considered+a+legal+business+document <-- Google says resume is not a legal document. Do you have any citation that it _is_ a legal document?

Comment: umm how about the LINK YOU JUST GAVE ME https://i.imgur.com/FFPMDLT.png

Comment: @corsiKa Please observe in your screenshot the *bold* part two sentences before what you circled, which says "A resume is not a legal document."

Comment: There's a difference between "legal document" as in "here's a filing I submit to the government" and "legal document" as in "there are legal ramifications to doing this wrong" and your first sentence is true in the absolute technical sense, but false in the simple sense. Which is why it's simply false. Your next sentence, saying you're perfectly fine to leave it off deliberately, is dangerously wrong and could conceivably land someone in jail. You honestly should delete this answer.

Comment: @corsiKa https://www.google.com/search?q=can+you+legally+leave+a+job+off+of+your+resume Since the entire first page says you _are allowed_ to leave a job off of your resume, I'm not too worried about this advice. There's a very obvious difference between leaving a job off of your resume vs outright saying "I never worked at any other jobs".

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations for the new job offer. You are overthinking it.

Full time employees are more valuable in the job market than interns, as showed by the total compensation.

You should have mentioned that you were a full time employee at that time, it would give you a little bit more power during offer negotiation.

> I am afraid it is too late and I will lose the job if I mention it.

No, if you mention now, they realize they had a good deal :)

Answer (score 3):

HR doesn't care about your CV. Or *almost never* cares. The only parts that *might* matter are things related to specific job requirements, because if you later have an issue they can rely on those to fire you (if you didn't meet requirements) or to cover themselves. This might apply to education - e.g., if a job *requires* a 4-year degree then your CV showing that is at least proof that you claim it, though the ultimate proof is an official transcript or similar document from an educational institution. Other items might include security clearance (hopefully those actually are checked by HR before hiring), legal right to work in a particular location or job (citizenship or appropriate visa) and similar things.

But your job history? Not relevant *at all* in most cases. Even if a job posting says "5 or more years of industry experience", that is usually not a strict requirement but rather a way to find experienced people. Using that example, sometimes personal study and projects can substitute for paid job experience and an above average employee can get 5 years worth of "ordinary" experience in 2 years of a high-pressure, high-achievement job.

All the more so in your specific case. They hired you based on your experience up to the interview. Except if you were fired because of wrongdoing, what you did between the interview and when you started work is of no consequence. If you were fired due to problems outside your control - e.g., the company closed a division and let lots of people go, and interns would be the first to go - that wouldn't be an issue. Certainly moving up from intern to full-time would be a plus - but not a problem if not reported.